# Access Style property through CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there anyway i can access the style property for the particular div? For example, I have a code like below

```
<div class="testing" style="background-color:#ff00ff;">
This is my test Paragraph
</div>
```

I want to apply some other background color for this division. But i don't want to modify the class "testing", because it is being used in some other places also. Is there anyway using CSS only to access the style property and apply my new color?

Comment: What do you mean by "access the style property"?

Comment: style="background-color:#ff00ff": this style i want to modify it.

Comment: Why can't you just change it?  To `style="background-color:#00ffff"` for example?

Comment: the point that I find unclear about your question is : you are talking about a CSS class you don't want to modify but in your example, you are using inline-styles what is the context exaclty?

Comment: In some cases, dynamic controls will add the style properties. I want to modify only that? The class i have given being used so many places. I dont want to touch it. I want to modify the style property. Is it possible?

Comment: as you described things, you need to use jquery/javascript.

Comment: By “style property”, you seem to mean the `style` attribute. It is unclear what the class has to do with the issue. It is also unclear why you don’t just edit the style sheet in the `style` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [attribute selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp) may be what you are looking for:

```
div.testing[style="background-color:#ff00ff;"] {
    background-color: new_color !important;
}
```

Comment: Yes, inline styles have higher precedence so I added `!important` to the style definition. Try now?

Comment: This seems to solve the problem presented, but note that a) the rule affects any `div` element with that attribute, not just “this element” (it is not clear from the question how “this question” can be identified), and b) when you need `!important`, the odds are that a fundamental design mistake has been made earlier.

Comment: It is working fine. I think it should be like this div.testing[style="background-color:#ff00ff;"]{background-color:new_color !important;}

Answer (score 0):

You can create another class and overwrite necessary property:

```
.testing-active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<div class="testing testing-active"></div>
```

Comment: Think it is a dynamic code. How can i add new class without using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a style that has higher priority than the style. You could use the `!important` attribute to do that:

```
<div class="testing" style="background-color:#ff00ff;background-color:red !important;">
```

Big important caveat: whatever it is you're trying to do doesn't sound like a good idea, because the code will be very difficult to maintain. What is the underlying problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am using some controls (For ex: Sharepoint, DNN) for my site. If you use that controls it will add inline styles for some division. I want to modify the style property to get my look.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the elements with this certain style like this:

```
.testing[style="background-color:#ff00ff;"] {
    /* put your attributes here*/
}
```

but you cannot change the `background-color` attribute since this one has a higher priority in the html.

see this:

```
.testing[style="background-color:#ff00ff;"] {
    background-color: #00f; /* not possible */
    margin: 30px; /* possible */
}
```

what you can do is add a new attribute to your html like this:

```
<div class="testing" changecss="true">
    This is my test Paragraph
</div>
```

and add this css:

```
.testing[changecss="true"] {
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

---

See the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vArEm/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

"Think it is a dynamic code. How can i add new class without using javascript? "

The Answers is **You cannot** add a new class using CSS dynamically/ runtime. The only way to do it is by using javascript/jquery:-

```
HTML:
    <div id="mydiv" class="testing" style="background-color:#ff00ff;">
    This is my test Paragraph
    </div> 

JQUERY: 

    $('#mydiv').css('background','#ColorCode');
```

This way your class also wont change( since its being used in other places) and you can change the background also.

Can i ask why you are trying to achieve this using CSS?

Comment: I know all about this bhavya. Even i also dont want to add new class. I am looking for a pure CSS solution. hp4k and frieder answers are given some direction to me. Once I will find the answer I will post here also.